# How do nested resources work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

As the official site, I defined two models `Post` and `Comment`. `Comment` is nested in `Post`.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

So I can use `@post.comments` to access all comments a post own. In console:

```
$ post = Post.new()
$ post.comments.class
> Array
```

But:

```
$ post.comments.respond_to?("build")
> true
```

Why? An array has the method `build`? How did Rails do? And how can I know other hidden methods of `post.comments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `resources` calls are in your `routes.rb` file, which only deals with the URL parsing side of Rails. It's nothing to do with the associations between your models, which are set up using `has_many` and `belongs_to` calls in the relevant model files. Ignore the routes file for now as it's not related to the main part of your question.

With respect to associations, you'll find that `post.comments` is not returning you an `Array`, it's actually returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. A `Relation` object is *like* an array - in fact any method you call on it which isn't relation-specific (like `build`) is actually passed on to an `Array` representation of the `Relation`'s contents. So, when you call `post.comments.length`, the `comments` association object is calling `.length` on its internal array.

One of the consequences of this is that calling `post.comments.class` actually passes on the `.class` call to the Array too!

So, what can that `Relation` object actually do? Since the association is set up by the `has_many` call, you can find out in the `has_many` [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many). Similarly for a `belongs_to` association

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can add or change any method in any object. You can even add a new method to a string instance, for example:

```
x = "xyzzy"
x.name     # => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "xyzzy":String
x.instance_eval do
  class << self
    define_method(:name) {"I got a name"}
  end
end
x.class    # => String
x.name     # => "I got a name"

y = "other"
y.class    # => String
y.name     # => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "other":String
```

That `build` method might have been 'added' to an instance of Array returned by the `comments` accessor, created by a `has_many` macro. *(As Gareth pointed, Rails complicated things a little, and the associations do not work this way. However, extending the objects may be a more 'clean' way in comparison to working as transparent proxy. Consider my example as a ruby-related, not rails)*

As for the second part of your question, you may know the methods of a given object by accessing its `methods` function. It returns the names of all the (public) methods defined for this object. *(If you want private ones, see the `private_methods` function.)*

In my example `x.methods` would include also the newly defined "name" method, but `y.methods` will not.

There are also other functions in ruby, with which you can examine the objects. You may find them in [Ruby API documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/). The API may have some (usually slight) changes in various versions of ruby. See the documentation for the version you are using.

If you want to examine the code of some method, then it may be a little problem, because the "executable code" of a function may be created by many ways: it may be a copy *(alias)* of another function, it may be created dynamically by using `eval` function, and so on.

Knowing the name of the method you may 'grep' the source code you have available, and maybe the method you want has not been created dynamically.

I see that the project [ParseTree](http://blog.zenspider.com/parsetree/) is still alive. Maybe you will find it helpful, if you really want to know the code of a function to which you do not have sources.

Comment: `x.methods` just lists all methonds. But I want their meaning(i.e. Rdoc).

Comment: Rdoc (meaning: comments) are not connected to the 'body' of the method. Knowing the _name_ of the method you may try to browse (grep) the sources. But a method may be added to an object as an alias, defined by calling `eval` or on many other ways. There was some project called 'parsetree', which aimed at 'decompiling' the ruby code, but I haven't used it.